# Port Scanner on with Bash

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash
host=$1
startport=$2
stopport=$3

function pingcheck
{
  ping = `ping -c 1 $host | grep bytes | wc -l`
  if [ $ping > 1 ]; then
    echo "$host is up";
  else
    echo "$host is down quitting";
    exit
  fi
}

function portcheck
{
  for ((counter=$startport; counter<=$stopport; counter++))
  do
    (echo > /dev/tcp/$host/$counter) > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$counter open"
  done
}

pingcheck
portcheck
```

I tried testing the script by passing 127.0.0.1 1 5 to it from the terminal but all i keep getting is ping: unknown host = 
127.0.0.1 is down quitting. Tried with other IP Addresses as well, I got the same output. I was following instruction from a book as I am new to shell scripting. It will be helpful if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Start with https://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: `(echo > /dev/tcp/$host/$counter) > /dev/null 2>&1` seems like a convoluted way to write `echo >/dev/tcp/$host/$counter 2>/dev/null`.

Comment: You have extra space... should read `ping=$(ping -c 1 $host | grep bytes | wc -l)`. Checkout @melpomene's site - very good advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some comments inline:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=$1
startport=$2
stopport=$3

function pingcheck
{
  ping=`ping -c 1 $host | grep bytes | wc -l` #Don't use spaces before and after the "="
  if [ $ping -gt 1 ]; then #Don't use >, use -gt
#  if [[ $ping > 1 ]]; then #Or use [[ and ]], but this won't work in all shells
    echo "$host is up";
  else
    echo "$host is down quitting";
    exit
  fi
}

function portcheck
{
  for ((counter=$startport; counter<=$stopport; counter++))
  do
    (echo > /dev/tcp/$host/$counter) > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$counter open"
  done
}

pingcheck
portcheck
```

Variables in bash are always in the format:

```
VARNAME=VALUE
```

You should not put spaces in between there. VALUE could be an expression using `` or using `$()`. `$()` is usually the preferred way, because you can do `$(something $(something))` and you can't do `something `something``.

The syntax of `if` is:

```
if EXPRESSION
then
  something
fi
```

An expression is in `sh` always a call to an application. `[` is an application usually used in ifs. You can get a really good manual of `[` by doing `man [`. `Bash` has native support for `[[`, which isn't an application, but can do more than [.